# VBA SaveAs in Notepad++ not working

Tags: vba, notepad++

I have the following code that generates the report and copies it into Notepad++, but it just doesn't save it as needed. Can anyone help please?
There are no error codes it generates.

```
Sub Main

Dim nppl

stattempname = ActiveDocument.FullName
stattempname = Replace(stattempname, ".pcb", "_STATS.txt")

On Error Resume Next
staFile = stattempname
Kill staFile
On Error GoTo 0

Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
Dim strText As String

strText = stattempname

objData.SetText strText
objData.PutInClipboard

STATCommand = ""
STATCommand = STATCommand & "Application.ExecuteCommand(""Reports"")" & vbCrLf
STATCommand = STATCommand & "ReportsDlg.SelectReportFilesForOutput.Selected(1) = true" & vbCrLf
STATCommand = STATCommand & "ReportsDlg.Ok.Click()" & vbCrLf
Application.RunMacro "",STATCommand

On Error Resume Next
nppl = Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe")
AppActivate nppl
SendKeys "^+s", True
SendKeys "^v~", True
SendKeys "%{F4}", True
nppl.SaveAs FileName:="" & stattempname
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any errors if you remove all the `On Error`-statements?

Comment: Why not just write the text file directly from VBA?

Comment: There is no error if I remove the On Error statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close (alt+F4) before `nppl.SaveAs()`.

**But** `nppl.SaveAs`  is not valid because you cannot control Notepad++ like that, you would need to send the correct keys to save which is very ugly.

If you just want to save the file:

```
stattempname = "c:\null\somefile.TXT"
strText = "Hello World"

Dim hF As Integer: hF = FreeFile()
Open stattempname For Output As #hF
    Print #hF, strText
Close #hF
```

If you want to have it open in NPP, simply open it after the save:

```
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe " & """" & stattempname & """", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: I'll do it this way instead.